# How to use Appium on Flutter Android app whose old code is in Native Android and new code in Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, appium, webdriver-io, webdriver-io-v4

For Native Android We are using Appium with **webdriverio** and **UIAutomator2**, but when we use same of Flutter, it is not working properly. We are not able to send Keys or identify particular element.

When we use Appium Inspector on Native App side we are able to inspect each and every element on UI properly, whereas for Flutter it is combining UI element in one group as it as View

I am using Flutter Version 1.22.6

I need proper solution which will work on both Native Android and Flutter

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

I also need to know this, am using Appium Inspector but the flutter elements all merge together is one big element.
I can see the big element using xpath but would like to be able to see each element separately in Appium Inspector.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33028140)